# Bootstrap 3 - how to achive full width in one button in group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: btn group]

```
<div class="input-group">
  <button class="btn btn-default full-width">
    <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> Fills remaining width</span>
  </button>
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="submit">
    <button class="btn btn-default">
      <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've used the above html to create the top button group. I would like to tweak it to achieve a button group more like the one underneath, where you don't have rounded corners on the right side of the widest button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.full-width {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 0;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.full-width span i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

In case anyone else is interested, adding these styles to my **.full-width** class did the trick. I'd be interested to see if anyone knows a Bootstrap 3 only way to do achieve the same appearance.